# How to get an array that summarizes sometimes repeated negative or positive values, also writing the number of repetitions in a separate column?

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I got a list with "Move" `(Column C)` values.

---

How to create "Sorted" list `(Column E,F)` , which repeat number in `Column F` and write action in `Column E` as 1, if next value go opposite way from zero;

And summarize 2 or more numbers in `Column F`, and write action in `Column E` as 2 or more, if they going together same way from zero;

?

---

Screenshot shows correct result:

[image]

> Google Sheets example link:
>   https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13WL9pD7glAZxOIhsXq6k-ZG0Z8bbGAmMOhtGrW3mRTA/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I came up with in cell E1 on the mk.idea tab

=ARRAYFORMULA(array_constrain(query({C2:C\LOOKUP(A2:A;filter({A2:A;1}; sign({C2:C;0})<>sign(n(C:C))))};"select Count(Col2),sum(Col1),Col2 where Col2>1 group by Col2 label Count(Col2)'Sorted',Sum(Col1)''";0);9^9;2))

Does that give you what you're after?